# How to fix the error "ERROR: Error 1215: Unable to add foreign key constraint"?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I made a diagram (EER) in MySQL-Workbench and trying to do "Forward Engineer to DataBase" gave me this error "Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint" and can't identify the error in the code.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Code:

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Schema loja1182

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin ;
USE `loja1182` ;
```

Table `loja1182`.`distritos`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`distritos` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `distrito` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`clientes`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`clientes` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `morada` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `data_registo` DATE NOT NULL,
  `nrEncomendas` INT(11) NULL,
  `idDistrito` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_clientes_table11_idx` (`idDistrito` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clientes_table11`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idDistrito`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`distritos` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`utilizadores`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`utilizadores` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `total_acessos` INT NULL,
  `idCliente` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_utilizadores_clientes_idx` (`idCliente` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_utilizadores_clientes`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`clientes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`tiposencomenda`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`tiposencomenda` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`estadosencomenda`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`estadosencomenda` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estado` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`encomendas`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`encomendas` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCliente` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` DATE NULL,
  `idEstado` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idTipo` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `valor` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_encomendas_clientes1_idx` (`idCliente` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_encomendas_tiposencomenda1_idx` (`idTipo` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_encomendas_estadosencomenda1_idx` (`idEstado` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_encomendas_clientes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`clientes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_encomendas_tiposencomenda1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idTipo`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`tiposencomenda` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_encomendas_estadosencomenda1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idEstado`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`estadosencomenda` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`categorias`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`categorias` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`iva`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`iva` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `taxa` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`artigos`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`artigos` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `precos` FLOAT NULL,
  `idIva` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `stock` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `idCategoria` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_artigos_categorias1_idx` (`idCategoria` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_artigos_iva1_idx` (`idIva` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_artigos_categorias1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCategoria`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`categorias` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_artigos_iva1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idIva`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`iva` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table `loja1182`.`linhasencomenda`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`linhasencomenda` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idEncomenda` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idArtigo` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantidade` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_linhasencomenda_encomendas1_idx` (`idEncomenda` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_linhasencomenda_artigos1_idx` (`idArtigo` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_linhasencomenda_encomendas1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idEncomenda`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`encomendas` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_linhasencomenda_artigos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idArtigo`)
    REFERENCES `loja1182`.`artigos` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ERROR:

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:

```
    Table `loja1182`.`encomendas`

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `loja1182`.`encomendas` (
      `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `idCliente` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `data` DATE NULL,
      `idEstado` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `idTipo` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `valor` FLOAT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      INDEX `fk_encomendas_clientes1_idx` (`idCliente` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_encomendas_tiposencomenda1_idx` (`idTipo` ASC),
      INDEX `fk_encomendas_estadosencomenda1_idx` (`idEstado` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `fk_encomendas_clientes1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`)
        REFERENCES `loja1182`.`clientes` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_encomendas_tiposencomenda1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`idTipo`)
        REFERENCES `loja1182`.`tiposencomenda` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_encomendas_estadosencomenda1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`idEstado`)
        REFERENCES `loja1182`.`estadosencomenda` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 10 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Comment: Which table is getting that error?

Comment: @Barmar - //Table `loja1182`.`encomendas`//

Comment: in mysql 8.0.18 all tables are created, only with warnings because of INT(11), where he doesn't like the (11) any more. Which version if mysql are you using?

Comment: @nbk - Ok, my mysql was out of date.
I will try after updating

Comment: @nbk - Thanks, it worked!